# How do I load locally saved icons on "new tab" homepage firefox?

Tags: firefox, icons, gui, favicon

I would like to know if it is possible to load icons stored on my computer in the "new tab" homepage of firefox. This came out because when firefox starts, it takes massive time to load the icons on the homepage, thus I'm trying to load these icons from my local storage.
In the icon field, I tried to put `file:///home/user/.mozilla/home_icons/icon.(png|svg)`, but it says that it's not a valid URL. I created a vsftp server and again, in the field, I put `ftp://localhost/path/to/file/.mozilla/home_icons/icon.png` without success.
I would like to know if the icon must be loaded from an HTTP protocol or if I have any different options to have my so desired icons...
[here's an image of the dialog window and the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfgFJ.png)

[another example with "file:///".](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtJfU.png)

PD: both of the links work when requested.

(I already read [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1358289/how-are-the-icons-for-top-sites-in-the-firefox-new-tab-rendered) and the icon is the right size.)

Comment: Have you tried with a local HTTP server?

Comment: I'll try, I just noticed this option when I wrote the question... I'll come back and post the answer if it works (it should, I guess). Thank you.

Comment: @gronostaj It turns out it works, but I find this is an undesired/bloated solution. I would like to know if anyone knows how firefox handles and _stores_ these icons.